# Dont include Ebeans Variable in SQL Statements

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, entity, ebean

I have an Ebeans Entity class which looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long userid;
    @Constraints.Required
    private String username;
    private boolean active;
    private String img;
    private String status;
    private int value;
    private int gender; // 0 = female, 1 = male
    private int orientation; // 0 = straight, 1 = gay, 2 = bi

    private int listIndex; // used to store listindex for page references
    private int precessor; // used to link the pages
    private int sucessor;

    private static final int USER_AMOUNT = 50;

    /* FINDER */
    public static Model.Finder<Long,User> find = new Model.Finder<Long, User>(
            Long.class, User.class
    );
```

the `listIndex` `precessor` and `sucessor` variables are needed in the object, but do not exist in the database. The Finder believes they are, which makes my SQL Statements fail.

So my question is can I somehow tell the Finder NOT to include this three variables in the SQL statments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`@Transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation on fields you don't want to persist, like

```
@Transient
private int listIndex;
```